# UICollectionView Header Issue, Headers doubling up

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

My header view in my `UICollectionViews` seem to double up when scrolling.
Header 1 scrolls up -> Header 2 is now in Header 1 location.
Scroll down and Header 1 now shows Header 1 and Header 2. Here's my code:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {

    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(134, 2, 53, 16)];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hole %i", indexPath.section + 1];

    [reusableview addSubview:label];
    return reusableview;
}

return nil ;
}
```

[image: image of issue]

I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 UILabel *_label;
 - (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {

    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(_label)
    {
        [_label removeFromSuperView];
    }
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(134, 2, 53, 16)];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hole %i", indexPath.section + 1];

    [reusableview addSubview:label];
    _label=label;
    return reusableview;
}

return nil ;
}
```

Comment: Sort of works, the top and bottom headers now appear normal but all headers in between are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample

```
 - (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
       viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind 
                             atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// You can make header an ivar so we only ever create one
if (!header) {

    header = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind
                                                withReuseIdentifier:@"ident"
                                                       forIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect bounds;
    bounds = [header bounds];

    UIImageView *imageView;
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header-background"]];

    // Make sure the contentMode is set to scale proportionally
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    // Clip the parts of the image that are not in frame
    [imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    // Set the autoresizingMask to always be the same height as the header
    [imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    // Add the image to our header
    [header addSubview:imageView];
}
return header;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[reusableView makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Comment: I'm sorry.  Try reusableView.subviews instead of just reusableView.  The point is to get rid of the subviews in reusableView as they contain leftover views from the previous scroll dequeue.